# Jquery not working with css position top left?

Tags: jquery, css, button, slider, position

I put css and jquery to try and make a slider that moves up and down, but it's not working.

CSS:

```
div#container img#slider_img {
                float:left;
                position:relative;
                top:0px;
```

jQuery

```
$(document).ready(function(){
            $('#btn_1').click(function(){
                $('#slider_img').css({'top','0px'});
            });
            $('#btn_2').click(function(){
                $('#slider_img').css('top','-400px');
            });
            $('#btn_3').click(function(){
                $('#slider_img').css({'top','-800px'});
            });
            $('#btn_4').click(function(){
                $('#slider_img').css({'top','-1200px'});
            });
        });
```

I manually changed the CSS position for top to -400, -800, and -1200 and it worked, but I can't seem to get jQuery to process the css properties...

Answer (score 1):

try with `{'top':'0px'}` use `:` instead of `,`

in Object literals notation `{}` the property (*key*) *assigner* is `:`
while in Arrays `,` is the delimiter.

Answer (score 0):

Beside the `{"":""}` object literals notation typo...

**JS** if more fun than you might think,
if you need a constant move of `400px` why not simply use

```
#btn_0 #btn_1 #btn_2 #btn_3
```

**starting from 0!**
After every click, if you take that number out of the clicked element, you get this simple math:

```
 -0 * 400 = move to -0px
 -1 * 400 = move to -400px
 -2 * 400 = move to -800px
 ..........etc
```

```
$(function(){ // DOM READY FUNCTION SHORTHAND

   $('[id^="btn_"]').click(function(){
        var N = this.id.split('_')[1]; // Get the number
        $('#slider_img').stop().animate({top: -N*400}, "slow");
   });

});
```